# Laravel view with variable, missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am losing too much time for (I am sure) a small missing, but I am not able to find it. 
Here my issue.

I want to create an open blade, so without authentication, with a variable parameter in the URL.

Here my codes

```
// routes/web.php
  Route::get('/{org_id}/tickets/ext/index', array('as' => 'tickets.ext.index', 'uses' => 'Ext\ExtTicketsController@index'));


// Ext\ExtTicketsController
 public function index(Request $request, $org_id)
 {
   //$org_id = 'my_organization';
   //dd(app()->getLocale());
   $locale=substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

   return view('tickets/ext/index')
   ->with('org_id',$org_id)
   ->with('locale',$locale);
 }
```

When I try to land on http://localhost/app/public/en/**my_organization**/tickets/ext/index I get error, for which I don't understand origin:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: tickets.ext.index] [URI: {locale}/{org_id}/tickets/ext/index]
```

I have the blade into views/ticket/ext/index file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: turn this `public function index(Request $request, $org_id)` to `public function index(Request $request, $locale, $org_id)` - you probably have a route group covering that route - which is looking for locale.

Comment: Thanks Ersoy, but it does not work. It works if I remove {org_id} from the route and /my_organization/ variable from the URL.....but I want to customize the URL according to the org_id

Comment: you were right, I added to the function the $locale. Now dd($org_id) gives me "my_organization". Nevertheless I am still getting the same error....:(

Comment: you need to update your blade if there is any `route(....)` which is lack of locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this, I hope it'll work

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/{org_id}/tickets/ext/index', 'Ext\ExtTicketsController@index');


// Ext\ExtTicketsController
public function index($org_id)
{
   $org_id = $org_id';
   $locale=substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
   return view('tickets.ext.index',compact('org_id','locale'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid this solution worked. Moreover I discovered that I had another small (and stupid) error :)

Comment: @Echecivuole Bro if it's worked for you then can you mark my answer as correct ? And you can tell me about your another error as well